# Java - Convert a ArrayList to coma separated strings with double quotes around each string

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

I am trying to convert a string arrayList to comma separated strings with double quotes around each string. I can write the code, But looking for any existing utility methods out there like apache StringsUtil.

my expected output is like "string1","string2","string3"

Comment: You should atleast Provide your research refer :- http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: N.V Prasad -- you should atleast read what I have said. I have clearly said, I can write the code. but looking to see whether there is any utility method already exists in JDK or any other third party tools.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

`String output ="";`

`for(int i = 0; i < arraylist.size(); i++){`
`output+="\""+arraylist.get(i)+"\""+i==arraylist.size()-1?"":",";`
`}`

Or

`String str = "\""+StringUtils.join(arraylist.toArray(new String[0]),"\",\"")+"\"";`

Answer (score 0):

use StringBuilder instead to be more efficient, the problem with the previous answer is that it does string concatenation which, in certain cases, with certain types of strings, with certain quantity of concatenations, is going to be inefficient.

Instead, keep .append()'ing the elements you need and do a .toString() at the end.